# How to use a ColdFusion Component to re-use code?

Tags: coldfusion, cffunction

I'm trying to put together a footer in ColdFusion using a component. I want to be able to re-use the footer throughout my application, but only have to write the footer HTML once.

Here's what I have so far, but I'm unable to output the content.

```
<cfcomponent>
    <cffunction name="getFooter" access="public" returntype="string" output="yes">
        <footer>
            <div class="row text-center">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    Copyright © 2020 Company Name | <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#msgPrivacy"> Security and Privacy </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>
    </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>

<cfoutput>
    #getFooter#
</cfoutput>
```

I created a [cffidle here](https://cffiddle.org/app/file?filepath=8b5dcf68-013f-4025-9c67-6f89c722f7af/9db6ac1a-7105-4007-83bd-0682b96c6452/d71440f2-621c-49d4-8ad1-31ea3bedd1d1.cfm).

Comment: You might want to look at a framework like FW/1 . It provides all kinds of mechanisms to reuse code, including footers.

Comment: Are you doing the `<cfoutput>` in the same file as the `<cffomponent>`?

Comment: A separate component for just the footer might work, but there are other ways I consider better.  I know, this is subjective.  Other options include writing a custom tag or using an included file.  Or, if appropriate, you can write the footer into the onRequestEnd function of your Application.cfc.

Comment: @DanBracuk those are interesting approaches. Full disclosure, I'm in the first 6 months of CF development. Never touched it before January 2020. Any advice you have on efficiency is greatly appreciated.

Comment: @ScottStroz - No. The output is in my .cfm file, and my components are in a cfc file. Does that help? I'm looking for the most efficient way to do this.

Comment: You can read about custom tags here.  https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/building-blocks-of-coldfusion-applications/creating-and-using-custom-cfml-tags/creating-custom-tags.html and included files here  https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-i/cfinclude.html.  If it were up to me, for a simple footer, I'd use an included file.  If you have co-workers, you should discuss it with them to see if there is a standard way of doing this in your organization.

Comment: @DanBracuk The way I was asked to do it is "there are multiple places where we're repeating the exact same code printing the footer. Roll this up into a library function, and then we can just call that library function."

Comment: My interpretation of a `library function` is a .cfm file with nothing but functions in it.  To get access to the functions, one would include this file.  It's equivalent to putting the function in a .cfc file and then creating an object.  As I said earlier, this is subjective.

Comment: OT, but if you're new to CF, I can't recommend http://www.learncfinaweek.com/ enough.

Comment: @Shawn - It would seem that most of the instruction on learncfinaweek is based on writing within script tags. Where I work, we only use cf tags.

Comment: It sounds like coding standards are already in place.

Comment: @JaredNewnam Sounds like a great opportunity to start pushing for a new standard. :-)

Comment: @Shawn - Can you clarify that? Are you meaning that we shouldn't work within script tags? Being a 6-month old in CF, your advice is valued. Thanks.

Comment: @JaredNewnam Sorry. My preference is cfscript over tags for most things CF. In the long run, it's cleaner looking and a bit more powerful/capable. Plus it'll look a lot more familiar to anyone coming from another language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Footer.cfc

```
<cfcomponent>
    <cffunction name="getFooter" access="public" returntype="string" output="no" >
        <!--- chr(169) is the copyright symbol --->
        <cfset var footer= 
            '<footer>
                <div class="row text-center">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        Copyright #chr(169)# 2020 Company Name | <a href="##" data-toggle="modal" data-target="##msgPrivacy"> Security and Privacy </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </footer>'>
        <cfreturn footer>
    </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

testPage.cfm

```
<!---<cfprocessingdirective pageencoding="utf-8">---> <!---Optional, as UTF-8 encoding is usually the default --->
<cfset footerObject=new Footer()>
<cfset footer=footerObject.getFooter()>
<cfoutput>#footer#</cfoutput>
```

Comment: Thanks, @DanBracuk. It was supposed to be Footer(). The word 'Test' is just a remnant of the code I used in testing it. I have made the correction.

Comment: The purpose of this was to create a more efficient way to deliver a footer. Writing out the function is on thing, but if I'm going to write out everything you have in testPage.cfm in every file where I want to put the footer, I might as well just put the actual footer. The goal was to write the footer function in a lib.cfc file, and then make one single call to `#footer#` where ever I want to use it.

Comment: The easiest way to do that is with a footer.cfm file and the `<cfinclude>` file.

Comment: @BKBK - Did you test this? I dropped the function in my .cfc file, where I have other functions. I placed the `cfprocessingdirective` and the two variables up top, and the `#footer` at the bottom of the page, before closing the `</cfoutput>`. It didn't work.

Comment: @JaredNewman, I tested the code exactly as presented here. It works. cfprocessingdirective is optional, as I have now indicated. What happens when you run without it?

Comment: Oh, when you say, "It didn't work", what do you mean? An error? Unexpected output?

Comment: @JaredNewman, that is just testcode to show you how to call the CFC. If I were to implement it in an application, I would do something like this in the onApplicationStart eventhandler in Application.cfc: `<cfset application.footer=new Footer().getFooter()>`.  Then, in the rest of the application, you only have to do: `<cfoutput>#application.footer#</cfoutput>`

Comment: @DanBracuk, I take it you mean the `<cfinclude>` "tag" instead of "file". In any case, it is debatable whether cfinclude is in fact "the easiest" way to do it.

Comment: Cfinclude is tied to the page-context. If you wanted to serialize the contents of a CFM page, then the method JaredNewman proposes might be "easier".

Comment: I find that `<cfinclude>` leads to things like includes within includes and ultimately makes the logical layout of the page all screwed up.

Comment: @BKBK - When I say "It didn't work", I mean that the footer wasn't displaying as expected.

Answer (score 1):

wrap the code like this

```
<cfcomponent>
    <cffunction name="getFooter" access="public" returntype="string" output="yes">
<cfsavecontent variable="footer">   
<cfoutput>     
<footer>
            <div class="row text-center">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    Copyright © 2020 Company Name | <a href="##" data-toggle="modal" data-target="##msgPrivacy"> Security and Privacy </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>
</cfoutput>
</cfsavecontent>
<cfreturn footer>
    </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>

<cfoutput>
    #getFooter()#
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I created a cffiddle and put in the OP. Please have a look.

Comment: https://trycf.com/gist/ee6e0aab64f46f9b58665e8d17daae3a/lucee5?theme=monokai

Comment: I removed cfcomponent so it can in fiddle

Comment: The reason it doesn't work as written is that you have to create an object before you can access a component's functions.

Comment: @user13895102, why not remove the cfcomponent tags from your answer, as you yourself have suggested? Otherwise, as it currently stands, your answer is actually incorrect.